# Strange Overlay with NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: )

Tags: swift, appkit, nsimage, nsworkspace

I am currently experiencing strange behavior when determining icons for files. When I determine icons using

```
let icon = NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: path)
```

it generally works fine. However, for some files, a "denied" symbol appears as an overlay. When I look at the corresponding icon in the debugger, a Decorated-Icon with the decoration `com.apple.icon-decoration.system.unsupported` is determined. **In Finder, Dock, or other programs, the symbol is displayed correctly.**

[image]

In the case mentioned, it is a website that has been converted into an app using the "Unite" application.

Why is `NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: path)` determining this overlay and is there a way to get the "normal" icon?

Comment: As a last resort, you can dig around those properties and empty our that [`decorations`](https://github.com/qingralf/iOS16-Runtime-Headers/blob/419e481cabff3393288aaa436f2d98e27bc2ed57/PrivateFrameworks/IconServices.framework/ISDecoratedIcon.h#L6) array with some ObjC runtime fuckery, but that'd be annoying. I wonder, could it be a permission issue? Does your app have access to read that app file?